# How to automatically export Selenium IDE test results as part of test suite?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), is it possible for my test suite to automatically export the test results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/file-logging-selenium-ide/) to save log to a file.

According to the documentation:

> This plugin for Selenium-IDE saves log messages to a file in real time at a user selectable log level. Once this plugin is installed, a FileLogging tab will be added to the options dialog and a FileLogging menu will be added to the log pane.